# DFA for all binary strings having even number of 0's or contains exactly two 1's

Tags: computation-theory, dfa, computation

I'm a bit confused with this question. I had tried to come up with a solution myself, referencing a few similar questions here and there, but I'm not sure if this is correct at all. Building an NFA to this is easy, but DFA is so confusing to me. I've inserted an image below of what I've done, but I don't know if it's right.

Solution that I've done:

DFA for each language:

[DFA for each language:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y1q36.png)

Combined DFA by applying union rule where F = (F1 x Q2) U (Q1 x F2), where Q1 = {A, B}, Q2 = {C, D, E, F} and F1 = {A}, F2 = {E}. Therefore, our accepting states are: F = {AC, AD, AE, AF, BE} and our transition graph is defined as follows:

[Combined DFA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KXWX8.png)

I don't know if there was a need for including the dead/trap state F, but I had read a similar question doing the same thing, so I just followed it. Is there a reason why F is included? And is there a way to do the problem without using it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By taking the union you have designed a DFA that accepts the union of the two languages, i.e. it accepts an input when it has an even number of "0", **or** it has exactly two "1" (or both). If that is what you need, then you have the correct DFA.

But if you need the *intersection* of both languages, then  = {}.

In that case, in your final diagram, only the state  should be an accepting state. None of the other states are accepting states.

The final state diagram can then be simplified by merging states  and  into just state  which is like a sink: from  both 0 and 1 will transition to .

[image]

#### Difference union and intersection

Given two regular languages  and  (they could be defined by DFAs), we have:

- The union ∪ is the language that accepts input that is accepted by  **or** that is accepted by , or both. So the language cannot accept less than what  accepts, nor less than what  accepts.
- The intersection ∩ is the language that accepts input that is both accepted by  **and** . So the language cannot accept more than what  accepts, nor more than what  accepts.

Just make sure you have the correct interpretation of this DFA challenge.

Comment: Ohh I see! But what is the difference between taking the union and intersection? And also may I ask, why do we take a trap state F? I followed a tutorial that did a similar thing, but is it possible to not include a trap state, or does that make the answer wrong?

Comment: I added a section on the difference between union and difference. About the trap state . This is needed when you want to define a *complete* DFA, i.e. where each state defines what happens when input 0 or 1 comes in. There is also the notion of an *incomplete* DFA: if a transition of either 0 or 1 is not included, it means the automaton halts in that state when it receives that input. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite_automaton#Complete_and_incomplete).

Comment: Oh, I have one more doubt. Like, I need the union of two languages since it says "all binary strings having even no of zeroes OR odd no of ones" -  so is the diagram that I gave correct in that case? And do I use the intersection DFA if the question specifies "having even no of zeroes AND odd no of ones?"

Comment: Yes, it is indeed like you say.

Comment: that was fast! thanks a lot!